# Android - Timed game with countdown which updates UI with remaining time, while user can still interact with UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, countdown

I'm designing a simple word game for Android.

The user will have to submit words associated with a topic/person, and will have around 20 seconds to do so.

The user inputs into a textbox and when they press 'enter', the inputted text will appear as a 'blob' on the screen. I want the UI to show a countdown message to inform the user how much time is remaining.  At the end of the countdown, the user will no longer be able to submit any more words and possibly taken to another screen/shown a popup that says 'Times up'.

I'm quite new to Android/Java development so not sure its multi-threading works and if I'd need to use it. I've seen Handlers/Runners suggested in other questions but I'm not sure they apply to my particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Everything which is not the UI, you write:

```
new Thread(new Runnable{
    //your code
}).start();
```

Your UI is still responsible, and your Background Tasks run in a different thresd

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I have the timer on a new thread, on the onTick() method can I send a message to the UI thread to display the remaining time?

Comment: Exactly, if a user starts a new round, you wirte your timer in a new thread like above, and inside this new thread you update your UI. You write Thread.sleep(1000) and after that you update your UI. Btw, to update your UI, you want to use Android's Handler.

Comment: PS if my answer was helpful, i would appreciate you press the checkmark to the left of my answer. thanka